# Create dynamic dictionaries from a list while it has a similar element

Tags: python

I am wanting to create some dynamic dictionaries from a list with duplicated items and with their index number in the list as key.

I tried this to do like:

```
theList = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']
newDict ={}
index = 0
for x in theList:
    while x == "A":
       newDict[index] = x
       index += 1    
print(newDict)
```

but even with hard coded (Not Desired) like `while x == "A":` I couldn't get the result back.

Desired output on printing: the dynamic dictionaries will look like:

```
{1: 'A', 2: 'A'}
{3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B'}
{8: 'C', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'B', 13: 'C', 14: 'C', 15: 'C', 16: 'C', 17: 'C' , 18: 'C'}
{19: 'D'}

{20: 'E', 21: 'E', 22: 'E', 23: 'E', 24: 'E',25: 'E', 26: 'E', 27: 'E', 28: 'E'}
{29: 'F', 30: 'F', 31: 'F'}
```

Comment: So the output is {"A" : 0, ...}?

Comment: Doesn't it lead to an infinite loop at `while`? What is the desired output?

Comment: If you are looking for `{0: 'A', 1: 'A', ...}`, try `newDict = dict(enumerate(theList))`.

Comment: Please share desired output

Comment: @j1-lee. I just saw your answer which is before mine. Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: @Corralien No, not at all!

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` to iterate over index and element of the list:

**Proposition 1**

```
from collections import defaultdict

newDict = defaultdict(list)
for idx, key in enumerate(theList):
    newDict[key].append(idx)

# Same code as above without defaultdict
# for idx, key in enumerate(theList):
#     lst = newDict.setdefault(key, [])
#     lst.append(idx)
```

Output:

```
>>> newDict
defaultdict(list,
            {'A': [0, 1],
             'B': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             'C': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
             'D': [18],
             'E': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
             'F': [28, 29, 30]})
```

**Proposition 2**

```
newDict = dict(enumerate(theList))
```

Output:

```
>>> newDict
{0: 'A',
 1: 'A',
 2: 'B',
 3: 'B',
 4: 'B',
 5: 'B',
 6: 'B',
 7: 'C',
 8: 'C',
 9: 'C',
 10: 'C',
 11: 'C',
 12: 'C',
 13: 'C',
 14: 'C',
 15: 'C',
 16: 'C',
 17: 'C',
 18: 'D',
 19: 'E',
 20: 'E',
 21: 'E',
 22: 'E',
 23: 'E',
 24: 'E',
 25: 'E',
 26: 'E',
 27: 'E',
 28: 'F',
 29: 'F',
 30: 'F'}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Corralien and appreciate for what have you done but I am affraid this is not what I am looking for. what I need is creating 6 dynamic dictionaries (As I have A,B,C,D,E, and F listed in `theList`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `enumerate`:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

theList = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F']

output = [dict(v) for _, v in groupby(enumerate(theList, start=1), key=itemgetter(1))]
print(output)

# [{1: 'A', 2: 'A'},
#  {3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B'},
#  {8: 'C', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C', 15: 'C', 16: 'C', 17: 'C', 18: 'C'},
#  {19: 'D'},
#  {20: 'E', 21: 'E', 22: 'E', 23: 'E', 24: 'E', 25: 'E', 26: 'E', 27: 'E', 28: 'E'},
#  {29: 'F', 30: 'F', 31: 'F'}]
```

`enumerate` creates an iterator of pairs `(1, 'A')`, `(2, 'A')`, ..., and then `groupby` cuts it into pieces based on the second item (by setting `key=itemgetter(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can create dynamic variables with the `globals` or `locals` builtins (I'm using `globals` below). This can be problematic though, so you need to be careful.

```
theList = [
    'A', 'A',
    'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
    'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
    'D',
    'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E',
    'F', 'F', 'F'
]

theDict = dict(enumerate(theList))

for item, value in theDict.items():
    dict_name = value + '_dict'
    if dict_name not in globals():  # avoid overwriting
        globals()[dict_name] = {
           k: v
           for k, v in theDict.items()
           if v == value
        }
```

I named the created variables for dictionaries as `[KEY]_dict` (e.g, `A_dict`, `B_dict`, etc).